# Why does cvGetCaptureProperty(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) return 0 on Windows?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I've seen this issue discussed on Linux. I have been running an application just fine with this call, and then suddenly it started to return 0 frames for a video that it was previously reporting the proper frame count for. I have no idea why this happened. I have not changed codecs on the machine. Is OpenCV this systemically buggy and useless? The most trivial things seem to fail regularly.

Answer (score 0):

I also use cvCapture to read video streams in OpenCV.

To return the Frame position, OpenCV needs to know the total length of the video stream.

If you are capturing from WebCAM, then Frame position will always be zero because it doesn't know the total time.

If you are capturing from a video file on your hard disk, Frame position will have some value.

At least i have these results...